# Is there a way to iterate Array() having string keys as index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

i have a code where i am creating a two dimensional array by using new Array(); here is my Code where i am getting some values from some REST api and manipulating values like this as shown in the code below

i have tried to iterate the object i am creating using available help from stack-overflow for the problems that are posted previously by other users, i.e trying to iterate array with key value pairs, using foreach loop or using key in object syntax with For loop.

```
    var CCTVCounterDictionary = new Array();
    var InitCCTVCounter = function (type, zoneName, quantityCCTV) {
        if (CCTVCounterDictionary[type] == undefined) {
            CCTVCounterDictionary[type] = new Array();
            if (CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName] == undefined) {
                CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName] = new CCTVCounter(type, zoneName, 0);
                CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName].Increment(quantityCCTV);
            }
        }
        else if (CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName] == undefined) {
            CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName] = new CCTVCounter(type, zoneName, 0);
            CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName].Increment(quantityCCTV);
        }
        else {
            CCTVCounterDictionary[type][zoneName].Increment(quantityCCTV);
        }
    };
```

and here is my js class that i am using to call Increment function for the object CCTVCounter that is being assigned to string index of each second dimension of array

```
    function CCTVCounter(type, zon, counter) {
        this.CCTVType = type;
        this.ZoneName = zon;
        this.CCTVCount = counter;
    }
    CCTVCounter.prototype.Increment = function (incrementBy) {
        if (incrementBy == undefined)
            this.CCTVCount++;
        else
            this.CCTVCount += parseInt(incrementBy);
    }
```

problem with this approach is that the length of my array stays 0 and if i try to iterate the array using foreach it doesn't seem to find key in CCTVCounterDictionary  with foreach loop or for loop syntax.

i am trying to find help for a piece of code to be able to iterate this array as shown in figure above but i am not able to figure it out how. any help is highly appreciated.

Below i am including log for how the output is being rendered by the code that is creating a 2 dimensional array

```
    SmartEnforcement.js: 202[] Banjir: Array(0) undefined: CCTVCounter {
        CCTVType: "Banjir",
        ZoneName: undefined,
        CCTVCount: 264
    }
    length: 0 __proto__: Array(0) Cadangan: Array(0) undefined: CCTVCounter {
        CCTVType: "Cadangan",
        ZoneName: undefined,
        CCTVCount: 26
    }
    length: 0 __proto__: Array(0) Sediada: Array(0) PJS: CCTVCounter {
        CCTVType: "Sediada",
        ZoneName: "PJS",
        CCTVCount: 368
    }
    PJU: CCTVCounter {
        CCTVType: "Sediada",
        ZoneName: "PJU",
        CCTVCount: 981
    }
    SEKSYEN: CCTVCounter {
        CCTVType: "Sediada",
        ZoneName: "SEKSYEN",
        CCTVCount: 504
    }
    SS: CCTVCounter {
        CCTVType: "Sediada",
        ZoneName: "SS",
        CCTVCount: 816
    }
    length: 0 __proto__: Array(0) length: 0 __proto__: Array(0)
```

Here is how i am invoking my main function to call the InitCCTVCounter

```
    InitCCTVCounter(marker.Type, f.attributes.ZON, marker.TotalCCTVS);
```

Comment: dude, post a data sample, and how you are invoking those functions

Comment: @iagowp Above i have posted the data sample and i am invoking the main function for counter using InitCCTVCounter(marker.Type, f.attributes.ZON, marker.TotalCCTVS);

Comment: I don't see any data sample

Comment: @iagowp : please see above a hyperlink labeled as (Console Log From Chrome) and below that is the line showing how i am invoking the function

Comment: Your question should have relevant data in the question. External links might be good for extra data, but I shouldn't need to leave SO to be able to understand your question properly

Comment: First of all, this is a bad practice. Just define them as objects. To loop over object properties you can use a `for in` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @iagowp : my apologies i wasn't sure how to copy a log but i have saved it to external file and making an edit for sample of data how it looks like

Comment: Arrays are just Objects with a special length property. Array methods depend on numeric integer properties (which are strings) and the special length. Adding named properties that aren't string integers means Array methods (i.e. those inherited from [*Array.prototype*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object)) will ignore them.

Comment: Can you put the original data you get from the API? You posted what you get after running your code (Also, you can put like only two of those, no need for the whole thing. We just need to understand what is happening

Comment: You're looking for a `Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think you have complicated Your logic to build a 2d array . I would suggest to use a **foreach** on your objects .

To iterate your object use it like below

```
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(function(x){
    // Your code to create array  
});
```

Build the array using **CCTVCounterDictionary.push** in it .

Answer (score 0):

What you have created is not an array but an jSon Object.
Tyring looping through it's keys using Object.keys 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: The OP is using an Array as a plain Object. There is only one [*JSON object*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-json-object). If you think this is a duplicate, you should mark it as such, not answer with links to duplicates.